# How to understand this theorem about convergence?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Since I don't know the exact name of this theorem, I am not able to search it directly in Google. There are so many subs in this theorem, and I am kind of new to the mathematical analysis. Also, I am also interested in how this theorem is applied. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Convergence almost surely implies convergence in probability, and if we have convergence in probability then there is a subsequence that converges almost surely. I think that this theorem looks clunky because it gives an if and only if condition which combines these two facts I wrote. This wiki page is very helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables and specifically https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_2

Comment: It is not clunky by any means. It is an elegant and very useful theorem. @Snaw

Comment: Still confused...

Comment: @Cooper I would suggest first seeing if you understand each of these two facts: convergence almost surely implies convergence in probability, and convergence in probability implies a subsequence which converges almost surely. You can find proofs of both of these facts in the wiki links. If you haven't seen an example of a random variable which converges in probability but not almost surely then you probably need to see that first.

Comment: Sure, will do! Thanks